# Why am I getting unititialized constant in my Rspec model test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to create a test with Rspec in my rails application but I keep getting the following error.

```
uninitialized constant Build
# ./spec/models/build_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.
```

I am running rails version 6.1.4.1. I also know that my model exists as I can create new objects that belong to that table in the ruby console.

here is my rspec file (spec/models/build_spec.rb)

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe Build, type: :model do
  it "Has a name"
  it "is not valid without name"
  it "is not valid with too short name"
  it "is not valid with too long of a name"
end
```

here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.4'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4', '>= 6.1.4.1'

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.3'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4.2'

  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 3.9.0'
end

group :production do 
  gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
end


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: do you have Build model in `app/models/` directory? Seems spec is not able to find the Build model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spec_helper` does not load the environment (this includes not loading the models). You could either require the model file explicitly in this spec or require `rails_helper` instead.

Comment: I had tried that before so I was confused until I came to the conclusion that I was missing the rails_helper.rb file somehow. So the solution was to run gem uninstall rspec-rails, then re-install rspec again and now my test is working. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have the right model inside the `app/models/` directory.

**spec/models/build_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Build, type: :model do
  it { expect(described_class.new).to be_a() }
end
```

**app/models/build.rb**

```
class Build < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Hope this works for you.